# Голоса против без каких-либо пояснений

Tags: предложение, голоса-против

За последнее время почти у каждого моего ответа имеется по голосу против. При этом нет ни одного комментария, указывающего на какой-либо недостаток. Вот смотришь и думаешь: "Ну и за что?"

Думаю, было бы неплохо требовать оставлять комментарий, когда голосуешь против. Можно даже анонимный, но хоть какой-то, чтобы было видно, чем пост не угодил.

Comment: Дело каждого - быть или не быть. Т.е. голосовать или нет.

Comment: Не нужно пытаться угодить кому-то конкретно в ответе или печалится из-за минусов, а нужно отвечать так чтобы текст ответа нес хоть какую-то пользу окружающим. Тогда и плюсов будет больше.

Comment: Неприятно видеть минус на каждый ответ, причём без единого комментария. Что дают такие минусы? Информацию о том, что что-то не так? Нет - за что он совсем непонятно, ибо нет вообще ни одного комментария. Информацию для кого-то ещё? Тоже сомнительно. У большинства ответов рейтинг примерно одинаковый, смотреть сколько там плюсов, сколько минусов даже при наличии соответствующих прав лень. А даже если посмотреть, вывод-то всё равно не из чего сделать.

Comment: Вообще-то серийными голосованиями против должны заняться админы. Это может оказаться личной местью.

Comment: Хотя к минусу комментарий необязателен, всё же хорошим тоном является объяснить, что не так.

Comment: @Qwertiy - http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/310001/most-evil-users - список тех, кому нужно мстить!

Comment: @PashaPash, `u.UpVotes * 1.0 / u.DownVotes` - что-то это не то. Надо же так: `u.DownVotes * 1.0 / (u.DownVotes + u.UpVotes)` - доля голосов против среди общего числа голосов.

Comment: @Qwertiy В запросе форумула "соотношение между злом и добром в душе человека" (во сколько раз чаще человек делает одно, чем другое), а вы предлагаете "пропорция зла в душе человека" (в каком проценте случаев человек поступает именно так). По-моему, обе версии имеют право на жизнь.

Comment: @Athari, а почему плюсы в числителе? Страница называется "самые злые пользователи", при этом запрос составлен так, что выводятся самые добрые.

Comment: @Qwertiy Это "исправление" от анонимуса, а не оригинал. Держите корректные версии: http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/300464/most-evil-users http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/310034/most-loyal-users

Answer (score 18):

Каждый раз, когда пользователь голосует против, ему выводится сообщение: "А не хотели бы вы оставить комментарий с объяснением?" Это было реализовано в рамках запроса [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes). Если пользователь игнорирует предложение, то на то его воля.

Это сообщение перестаёт выводиться, когда пользователь достигает 2К репы — предполагается, что к этому моменту он уже разобрался, как минусовать и как комментировать.

Идея анонимных комментариев предлагалась: [Enable Optional Anonymous Reasons for Downvotes on Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253531/enable-optional-anonymous-reasons-for-downvotes-on-questions). В этом посте присутствуют ссылки на похожие предложения. Какой-либо реакции со стороны администрации этот feature request не получил. Можете поставить плюсик и надеяться на лучшее.

---

Ну а чтобы ловить меньше минусов, рекомендации стандартные:

1. Пишите подробные сообщения. Короткие сообщения, в том числе состоящие практически только из кода, сваливаются в очередь на ревью и таким образом привлекают внимание проверяющих.
2. Относитесь уважительно к собеседнику. Если нечего сказать, лучше промолчать.
3. Выбирайте для ответа качественные вопросы. Если вопрос не соответствует формату сети SE, то некоторые пользователи минусуют даже верные ответы, чтобы отучить отвечать на оффтопик.

Ну это чисто так, под впечатлением от просмотра ответов в вашем профиле.

Comment: А что не так с уважительным отношением? А лучше, где?

Comment: @Qwertiy Антипример: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420725

Comment: Ну.. Да) Но вопросу вполне соответствует. Там же +0/-5 за вопрос тоже не спроста.

Comment: @Qwertiy А это уже п. №3. Зачем вообще отвечать на этот вопрос?

Answer (score 11):

Это искоренить нельзя никак, кроме как заставлять всегда оставлять комментарий к голосу. Но это явно противоречит концепции SO, как ресурса где `+/-` раздаётся легко  и просто. Благо концепция SO в этом смысле очень правильная - один `+` покрывает 5 минусов, поэтому я не вижу смысла морочить голову.

Да есть индивиды, которые тебе влепят минус только потому, что ты это ты, а качество ответа/вопроса их не волнует(кровная месть, не иначе). Простим им это, им уже и так по жизни досталось. А SO не хабр, тут о минусах вообще переживать не стоит.

Если ресурс будет жить, то потихоньку обрастёт нормальной аудиторией, которая полностью утопит мелочные минусы в праведных плюсах и наоборот.

Comment: Про утопление минусов понравилось. :)

Comment: Думаю так же не справедливо... когда ни за что просто  ставят Минус и всё.. сам сегодня столкнулся с такой проблемой http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/620619/php-%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-get-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81/620621#620621
Вот скажите, знающие люди, за что можно получить 2 минуса? конечно голосов ЗА больше в несколько раз, просто "За державу обидно", может и впрямь что то там не так? Вот если бы модераторы или редакторы смогли бы(при возможности) на такие вещи обращать внимание и предупреждать таких "мстителей" о некорректности их минуса - было бы OK)

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что заставлять человека объяснять свое мнение - не очень корректно. Как минимум по следующим причинам:

1. В противовес голосу "*против*" существует голос "*за*", который дает аж в 5 раз больше репутации, чем "*против*" отнимает.
2. Человеку может просто не понравиться вопрос по субъективным причинам. От этого он не лишается права выразить свое отношение голосом.
3. Человек может посчитать, что автор вопроса крайне недальновидный человек, раз задает вопросы подобного характера. Объяснение этого в комментариях будет ничем иным, как оскорблением. Зачем это нужно?
4. Голоса - не способ осуждения или поощрения, а скорее индикатор отношения сообщества к конкретному топику. Репутация, которая дается за них - уже последствия субъективного отношения этого сообщества.
5. Голос против - это лишь право, а не обязанность. Многие им охотно пользуются. Комментарий с советом автору вопроса - тоже лишь право, а не обязанность. Многие также охотно им пользуются.
6. Добавление предложенного вами правила сломает хоть какой-то вид демократии и свободы слова на этом ресурсе. А также потребует полный рефакторинг привилегий.

Соглашусь с вами, что если голосуешь, будь добр объяснить. Это разумный поведенческий шаблон) Но далеко не все люди разумны и самодостаточны настолько, чтобы не раскидываться минусами просто так, а у них тоже должны быть такие же права, как у тех, кому с воспитанием повезло больше.

Так что приходиться быть гибким. У них то

Comment: Так отношение к топику, а не к человеку.