# Настаивать на оставлении комментария при голосовании против вопроса с репутацией 0

Tags: предложение, вопросы, голоса-против

За некоторое время пребывания на SO заметил такую тенденцию. Вопросы получают отрицательные голоса чаще всего из за того, что:

- *Вопрос плохо отформатирован*

Думаю, справедливо будет подметить, что после правки сообщения либо самим участником, задавшим вопрос, либо другим участником, люди, проголосовавшие против вопроса только потому, что он был плохо отформатирован, не вернутся, чтобы снять свой отрицательный голос.

- *Вопрос затрагивает мало известную тему*

Часто можно заметить, как вопросы, тема которых мало освещена или касается, например, какого-то узкоспециализированного фреймворка/инструмента, обрастают парой минусов.

- *Вопрос задан новичком*

Как ни странно, но даже такое имеет место быть. Если вопрос задан человеком, репутация которого меньше 100, и в вопросе участник забыл указать какую-нибудь немаловажную деталь (по неопытности), вопрос тут же начинают засыпать минусами до тех пор, пока кто-нибудь более опытный не укажет ТС в комментариях на отсутствие в вопросе чего-то важного.

- *А не понятно из за чего (возможно из за сильной развернутости)*

Самое обидное, я думаю, это когда ты конкретно поставил вопрос, добавил минимальный самодостаточный пример кода, описал ситуацию, проблему, требуемое решение, но это все заняло довольно много места. Сам сталкивался с подобным отвратительным явлением. За что ставят минус - точно не понятно. Однако я думаю, что участнику просто лень это читать. Или он прочитал, но не знает как решить проблему и зол на потраченное впустую время. Ну или просто стиль изложения не понравился. Сложно сказать.

Вся **суть проблемы** в том, что вопросы, репутация которых отрицательна, обращают на себя куда меньше внимания в ленте, даже если вопрос сам по себе поставлен грамотно и решение найти можно. Это значительно снижает шанс того, что кто-то решит ответить на ваш вопрос. Ну или хотя бы просто откроет его. А шанс того, что он откроет его, прочтет, поймет, что минусовали зря и даст свой ответ вообще сводится к нулю.

**Было бы неплохо**, как мне кажется, вместо надписи "Если вы считаете, что сообщение можно улучшить, оставьте комментарий", принудительно заставлять писать комментарий, указывающий на то, почему вопрос поставлен некорректно. И делать это *только в том случае*, если после вашего голоса репутация уйдет в минус.

То есть если репутация была +5, а кто-то нажал на минус, то это нестрашно, все-таки большинство посчитало этот вопрос интересным. А вот прежде чем лишить вопрос шанса получить ответ (уйти в минусовую репутацию), следует заставить того, кто хочет это сделать, указать конкретную этому причину.

Если же репуация итак была -2, то, по логике, комментарий уже оставлен. А если участник, поставивший еще один голос против с этим комментарием несогласен, то пускай оставит свой комментарий, отражающий его негативное отношение к вопросу. Ну или оставит свое мнение при себе.

Мне кажется, что количество ответов на вопросы после введения этой практики должно порядком возрасти.

P.S. [Возможный дубликат](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), по сути, им не является.
P.P.S. Конкретные примеры у меня есть, но некоторые из них будет сейчас уже проблематично найти, а с авторами голосов против к некоторым вопросам просто не хочу обострять отношения.

Comment: предположим, что будет принудительное оставление комментария, кто гарантирует, что комментарии будут информативны?

Comment: _Мне кажется, что количество ответов на вопросы после введения этой практики должно порядком возрасти._ - скорее просто появится куча плохих вопросов вообще без ответов

Comment: в идеале, стоило бы добавить пример для каждой из выделенных групп

Comment: > скорее просто появится куча плохих вопросов вообще без ответов - сомневаюсь: рано или поздно, найдутся опытные участники, которые-таки поставят первый минус (что обычно и является решающим фактором)

Comment: Это если им не лень будет писать _обязательный_ комментарий, либо они напишут какую-нибудь шаблонную отписку в комментарии, ничего не поясняющую, в итоге либо минуса не будет вообще, либо не будет разницы с тем как сейчас, за исключением - времени реакции

Comment: @Grundy мы отходим от сути: не дать поставить минус туда, куда не надо. Если минус действительно нужен, то даже "шаблонная отписка" даст понять, что нужно подправить или почему ответ не может быть дан вообще. А если все нормально с вопросом, то это даст возможность избежать минуса-просто-так, что увеличит шанс получить ответ.

Comment: _то даже "шаблонная отписка" даст понять, что нужно подправить или почему ответ не может быть дан вообще_ - Пример: **ваш вопрос плохой** - как это может помочь что-то исправить? Либо чего-то избежать?

Comment: @Grundy я думал, что шаблонная отписка в вашем понимании - это что-то вроде "Укажите подробности" или "Что требуется получить в ответе?" или "Добавьте имеющийся код"

Comment: @Grundy ни разу не видел, чтобы в комментариях, было "ваш вопрос плохой".

Comment: @Grundy да и тревоги к комментариям никто не отменял

Comment: Очевидно, потому что комментарии не обязательны :-)

Comment: Суть этого комментария, не в том, чтобы что-то подсказать автору вопроса/ответа, а в том, чтобы **обойти ограничение** на постановку минуса

Comment: @Grundy смотрите в корень. Если человек попытается поставить минус по одной из вышеперечисленных причин (а это, считайте, минус просто так), то ему надо будет прокомментировать свое действие. Это поможет избежать **нынешних** минусов просто так. А если он оставит комментарий по одному из ваших шаблонов, то будет понятно, что минус был поставлен необоснованно, и другие участники сообщества это заметят. Соответственно можно будет пожаловаться на комментарий.

Comment: @smellyshovel вы предлагаете деанонимизировать минусы. зачем?

Comment: _Соответственно можно будет пожаловаться на комментарий._ - с какой формулировкой?

Comment: @PashaPash Я предлагаю запретить постановку необоснованных минусов. Если деанонимизация вас не устраивает, я совсем не против анонимизировать оставляемый комментарий.

Comment: @Grundy "другое"?

Comment: @smellyshovel, _я совсем не против анонимизировать оставляемый комментарий._ - тогда в чем смысл жаловаться на анонимный комментарий?

Comment: @smellyshovel "Если вы считаете, что сообщение можно улучшить, оставьте комментарий" - это просто стандартная текстовка. на самом деле если я считаю, что сообщение можно было улучшить - то я его или улучшаю правкой, или закрываю (если его нельзя улучшичть без участия автора). Минусы я ставлю на тех сообщениях, которые я вообще не хотел бы видеть на сайте.

Comment: в "другое" нужно написать **свою формулировку**.

Comment: @PashaPash не забывайте, что вы говорите про *себя*. Не все действуют так же грамотно, как вы.

Comment: @smellyshovel любой минус обоснован по определению - его же не просто наугад поставили. Но это обоснование субъективно. Поставивший считает что сообщение заслуживает минуса. Автор сообщения, естественно нет. И автор 100% поставит тревогу на комментарий "ваш вопрос - плохой". Что дальше? должен зайти модератор и решить, достоин ли вопрос минуса?

Comment: Хорошо, я так понял, к одному мнению мы не придем. Тогда переформулирую вопрос: что вы предлагаете делать с необоснованными минусами? Как их искоренять?

Comment: @PashaPash а, я понял. То есть по-вашему, необоснованных минусов на сайте не существует в принципе?

Comment: @smellyshovel я к тому, что вы практически предлагаете завернуть все минусы на ревью модераторам. хотя именно минусы сейчас являются одним из инструментов модерации сайта самим сообществом.

Comment: @smellyshovel я считаю что все минусы обоснованы. и что гораздо большей проблемой являются необоснованные плюсы.

Comment: @PashaPash что ж, тогда, я думаю, дальнейшего обсуждения быть не может. Соглашусь с вашим мнением только потому, что вы модератор и, по-видимому, что-то все-таки понимаете. Спасибо за аргументированный спор.

Comment: И вам, @Grundy , тоже

Comment: Примеры таких заминусованных вопросов отлично смотрелись бы в вашем вопросе. Думаю, есть как справедливо, так и несправедливо заминусованные. Во втором случае нужно анализировать и предпринимать какие-то меры, либо адресные (поговорить с теми, кто зря закрыл), либо массовые (написать на Мете пост с разбором ошибок). Но нужен живой пример, без примера все рассуждения абстрактны. ))

Comment: `ребята типа Вас, которых сообщество уважает` - небольшой процент участников, особенно новых, ещё не в курсе местных правил и "авторитетов". Они могут реагировать на "подписанные" минусы очень негативно. Вы бы хотели на каждый 20й свой минус получать скандал с оскорблениями продолжительностью два часа? Сейчас те, кто больше всех старается объяснять недостатки вопроса, получают больше всех оскорблений в свой адрес. Это не пустое предположение, это я по опыту обработки тревог вам говорю. ))

Answer (score 4):

Нужно сделать список шаблонных причин и поле для кастомной. Примерно как это в закрытии указано.

Комментарий нужно сделать анонимным.

Собственно всё: это даст информацию для спрашивающего, что ему стоит поправить в вопросе, чтобы на него быстрее ответили.

Comment: [meta-tag:статус-так-задумано] :-)

Comment: А ещё можно все ответы анонимными сделать.

Answer (score -4):

- Нужно сделать только поле для указания индивидуальной причины и задать минимальный лимит по символам в ней. Ввести наказание за невнятный комментарий (т.е. если человек ввел какой то произвольный набор символов а не читабельный текст).
- Комментарий нужно сделать гласным. Это явно материализует пользователя. Комментарии станут более обдуманными.

Comment: Скорее всего таких комментариев (гласных и объясняющих минус) почти не будет. В комментариях к вопросу @Grundy правильно заметил -- `"появится куча плохих вопросов вообще без ответов"`

Comment: @avp нельзя так наобум заявлять. Каким образом эти вещи вообще связаны? Если прежде чем поставить минус вопросу надо будет хотя бы подумать, то почему из за этого станет больше плохих вопросов?

Comment: @smellyshovel, из-за того, что люди (в своем большинстве) стараются делать что-то неприятное (в даном случае минусовать) анонимно. Вероятно, глубинные основы такого поведения закодированы на уровне генов (привычка выработана в ходе эволюции).

Comment: @avp так в том-то  суть! Сейчас они минусуют анонимно, а если *необходимо* будет объяснить, почему поставлен минус, то человек подумает, прежде чем его поставить!

Comment: @smellyshovel, правильно. Просто не будут ни минусовать ни объяснять (и отвечать тоже не будут). Результат -- `"появится куча плохих вопросов вообще без ответов"` / Но в принципе, Вы мыслите в правильном направлении, проблема существует.

Comment: @avp "просто не будут минусовать" - будут. Не будут те, кто, возможно, поставил бы минус зря. А вот ребята типа Вас, которых сообщество уважает и которые уже доказали, разбираются в происходящем, спокойно поставят минус (конечно, если он будет действительно необходим) и корректно пояснят, почему они это сделали. "проблема существует" - было бы куда лучше, если бы она решалась :)

Comment: @smellyshovel, так нам и сейчас ничто не мешает вести себя именно так -- поставить минус и в комментарии объяснить почему (или даже чаще -- написать комментарий без всяких минусов). Лично я считаю, что плюсом надо отмечать интересные для желающих отвечать (или возможно просто почитать и что-то новое узнать) вопросы, а минусом наоборот -- вопрос дурацкий, не стоит тратить время.

Comment: @avp "так нам и сейчас ничто не мешает вести себя именно так -- поставить минус и в комментарии объяснить почему (или даже чаще -- написать комментарий без всяких минусов)." - вы забыли суть вопроса. Мы пытаемся (изначально пытались, по крайней мере) избавиться от необоснованных минусов. То, что и сейчас можно себя так вести - это понятно. Но надо смотреть в корень. В общем ладно, я так понял, что все равно никто ничего делать не будет. Помечтали и полно :)

Comment: @smellyshovel, а вот насчет `"все равно никто ничего делать не будет"` Вы верно заметили. По крайней мере никаких коренных изменений тут не предвидится.