# Не давать возможность поставить дизлайк без комментария

Tags: предложение, голоса-против

Собственно, почему бы не запретить ставить дизлайк, пока не напишешь комментарий, чем тебя конкретно не устраивает тот или иной вопрос/ответ?

Обычный дизлайк не дает представления владельцу сообщения о том, что не так в нем => не может повысить его качество.

Введя такое ограничения, можно будет влепить дизлайк только после написания аргумента.

Comment: Поставил дизлайк без комментария .... и написал об этом комментарий ... черт ..

Comment: @Kromster комментарий, не объясняющий причину написания, бесполезен.

Comment: @alexolut *пишу этот комментарий, чтобы вам возразить* "ваш комментарий так же, не объясняет причину своего написания."

Comment: Мне кажется что когда репутация выше 3000 то минусы уже не сташны. А если находится фанатик которому вы не понравились (кстати раскрытие личности минусующих может породить таких) и минусует все ваши вопросы - система сама такое обнаруживает и делает откат. Я против такого нововведения. Такая модель будет плохо работать (увеличится к-во минусующих в-отместку, а причину придумают, а валидация причины - уже сильно усложняет проверку)

Comment: Да ладно, минусовать вопрос. Просто.... автора раздражает что по-каким-то причинам произошло "безпричинное" минусование одного из вопросов. Я с таким сталкивался. Как это можно разрулить... у меня пока идей нету.

Comment: Ваша идея на практике не так хороша, как кажется, так как люди чаще всего очень эмоциональны и не готовы к отрицательной обратной связи. Поэтому после написания комментария вольно или невольно втягивают в выяснение отношений и доказывание. Также я нередко получаю оскорбления и/или серийные голоса против произвольных постов. Каждый раз когда думаю писать такой комментарий готовлюсь к риску получить ведро помой и неадекватности.

Answer (score 8):

Связанные обсуждения:
1. [Настаивать на оставлении комментария при голосовании против вопроса с репутацией 0](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4013/15479).
2. [Require a comment explaining the reason for the first downvote on a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250177/1991579)
3. [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/1991579)
4. [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/260198).

> Обычный дизлайк не дает представления владельцу сообщения о том, что
>   не так в нем => не может повысить его качество

Дизлайк даёт понять, что с вопросом что-то не так.

В той же [Теории модерации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7420/15479).

> Всегда, когда это возможно, оставляйте небольшой поясняющий
>   комментарий к каждому сообщению, в котором вы выступили (или хотели
>   выступить) в роли модератора. Крайне важно, чтобы участники сообщества
>   могли изучить нормы сообщества и практики модерирования сайта.

Мы хоть и не модераторы, но голосование, фактически,- форма модерации. Так что, рекомендация к тому, чтобы оставить комментарий, есть.

> Обычный дизлайк не дает представления владельцу сообщения о том, что
>   не так в нем => не может повысить его качество.

Я расцениваю это как возможность самому осознать проблему. Человеку поставили дизлайк, это звоночек к тому, чтобы он подумал и осознал, в чём проблема.

Люди ленивые; многие привыкли, они хотят, чтобы за них всё сделали другие.

Если автор вопроса читал правила, то знает как правильно задавать вопрос. Если не читал, а на его вопросе появились минусы, то самое время восполнить пробел. Если человек не способен к самообучению и анализу, то, в целом, такой человек особой ценности сообществу не принесёт.

**P.S.** если вводить обязательные комментарии для голоса "против", то нужно ввести ещё обязательные комментарий для голоса "за", чтобы автор вопроса узнал, чем хорош его вопрос (:

**P.P.S.** даже если бы это было реализовано, то вариантов имплементации такого механизма всего несколько:

1. В лоб обязывать комментарии. Тогда:

   1. Люди будут оставлять левые комментарии, как сейчас в случае с правками происходит зачастую.
   2. Будут мстить в ответку.
2. Сделать комментарии анонимными, тогда некоторые участники будут злоупотреблять и писать всякий треш.

Answer (score 4):

Ваша модель работать не будет, потому что:

1. *Минус* -  это негатив, и если автор знает *кто меня минусует*, он может из чувства мести (или справедливости), *минусующему* добавить *минусов*, написав от фонаря причину (а если не от фонаря - еще хуже, придерется к какой-нибудь мелочи, и причина может оказаться неплохой). Да.. можно сделать валидацию причины... но это очень усложняет модель. Очередь на проверку вопросов есть, и что, создавать очередь на проверку.... коментов-на-минус? Не подходит. Так как у новичков вопрос один (ну... до 5-10 штук), а у вас больше (более 100, у вас сейчас более 600), то вы в репутации потеряете потенциально много, а новичок с репутацией 125+ - потеряет 10 балл. Поэтому люди с высокой репутацией начнут её хорошо так терять, и сообщество не будет довольно таким нововведением.

   P.S. Я часто, оставляя негативный комент, не ставлю минус, что б человек не связывал комент с тем, что минус поставил я, т.к. были случаи что минус + коммент = минус у тебя.
2. Есть вопросы спамерские (завуалированые, что не каждый понимает с первого прочтения что это спам), а также откровенный спам, есть вопросы троллинговые (встречал), есть вопросы просто не по теме. Есть вопросы - а решите-ка мне задачку, и другие случаи вопросов, которые ценности не представляют. Писать разьяснение почему мне не нравится один из видов вопроса - это занимает время, и думаю тоже сообществу не понравится.

Comment: Про новичков — неправда, так как голоса против начинаются с 125 репутации. А когда человек прошёл этот порог он уже сильно далёк от новичка и ему есть куда нахватывать "минусы".

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov да, я это не учёл. Но серию минусов я получал. Возможно 125 репутации... тоже новичёк, но продвинутый... подумаю как переформулировать....