# Предлагаю модерацию голосования "против"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, модерация, голоса-против

Напр., [нормальный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/895054/245943) получил -2...

Comment: Это не нормальный вопрос.

Comment: @Kromster Чем же он нарушает правила?

Comment: Вопрос сформулирован как "у меня есть ТЗ. Я сделал что-то. Разберитесь в чем тут дело и исправьте за меня".

Comment: @Kromster Вас смущает "ТЗ"? Я новичок, "ТЗ" - не в смысле, что мне что-то заказали, а в смысле "задание", техническое как ни посмотри. "Сделал что-то" - так лучше и не пытаться разобраться самостоятельно? В-третьих, Harry почему-то не счёл ниже своего достоинства ответить на "пакостный" вопрос. В-четвёртых, как Вам сама идея модерации голосования против :)?

Comment: Некоторые люди, видя минусы на вопросах/ответах, пытаются подсластить пилюлю и ставят плюсы. Если бы минусов не было, то они не поставили бы плюс. Причем за плюс дается больше репутации, чем снимается за минус. Так что это выгодно... Не исключено, что у вас как раз такой случай.

Comment: @VladSpirin А вы не могли бы более дружелюбно сформулировать почему данная идея нехороша, а не употреблять грубую и как мне кажется демотивирующую фразу ("идея бредовая") предлагать новые идеи?

Comment: Вадим, к сожалению у меня в этот момент нет возможности разводить тут полемику. Коммент удаляю, время появится постараюсь описать ход своих мыслей по данному поводу. Спасибо.

Comment: это дубль, такой вопрос пару месяцев назад был

Comment: @nick_n_a We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge. See "I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?" for alternatives to deletion.

Частое удаление вопросов с ответами может привести к тому, что вам будет запрещено задавать новые вопросы. Вы действительно хотите >выполнить удаление?

Comment: Я имел ввиду модерацию "минусов". Почитайте вот https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7835/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f/7841

Comment: И вот https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277/%d0%93%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9

Comment: Если раз в месяц будете удалять по одному вопросу - ничего не будет. Имеется ввиду что если будете злоупотреблять удалением, например... с целью рекламы спамить (а удалять что б за спам не успели закрыть). Или эксперементировать какой порядок слов в вопросе наберёт больше баллов - то вас заблокируют, или ещё какую махинацию придумаете... Есть люди - удаляют и всё, а есть, которые ищут брешь в системе - и заявляют что сайт "не верно работает", для последних сделано "предупреждение"

Comment: @nick_n_a Не удаляется

Answer (score 5):

1. Вы не сформулировали толком предложение по модерации.
2. Приведенный вами вопрос не является "нормальным". Пожалуйста ознакомьтесь со справкой по тому как задавать вопросы на StackOverflow. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

P.S. Идея модерации голосов мне кажется порочной в любом виде.