# Заметил тенденцию дизлайкать простые вопросы

Tags: обсуждение, голоса-против

Очень часто на простых вопросах появляются дизлайки. При этом вопросы нормально оформлены, достаточно описаны.

Напомню, что дизы **сделаны для понижения рейтинга тех учаcтников, которые не хотят разбираться в вопросе, вопрос непонятен и не несет пользы**.
Часто вопрос, который дизают понятен, он будет полезен всем новичкам, и выражает стремление разобраться - человек зашел, зарегался на SOru, нашел как задать вопрос и как его оформить, описал проблему(или вы считаете что это проще чем погуглить?). И таких ситуаций много

Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1461222/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-pip) 
или вот [еще](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1461299/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83-c)

У меня вопрос, зачем вы дизлайкаете простые вопросы?

Comment: Есть такое, я когда пишу простой вопрос, оставляю комментарий сразу, что вопрос служит цели иметь информацию на русском языке и отправляю на мету на релевантую тему. Это снижает вероятность, что вопрос закроют и полетят минусы, но точно не явлется гарантией. Есть ряд пользователей, кто против теоретических вопросов, переводов статей, документаций и проч. Есть не разобравшиеся в вопросе, есть кто осваивает очереди проверок и у них есть страх не пройти аудит и они подстраиваются под ожидание системы (мои догадки). Оставлять комментарий при минусе - хороший тон. Я обычно пишу "минус мой: причина"

Comment: Я вообще не дизлайкаю вопросы (кроме откровенного бреда), чего и вам всем желаю

Comment: Ну минусят и минусят, что смертельного? Сколько там рейтинга снимают за минус, два?

Comment: @yolosora дело в том, что с какого то момента аккаунту у которого минусуют вопросы, просто закрывают возможность задавать вопросы

Comment: И как относиться к такому вопросу? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1464656/195342 Ставить лайки — "аффтор, пеши истчо"? А кто-то ведь поставил... Блин, программисты опустились до уровня "Гугл есть — ума не надо!" Скоро будут спрашивать "сколько будет дважды два? Срочно надо!"

Comment: Нужно к дизлайку комментарий приделать, чтобы человек объяснил, за что

Comment: @rotabor почитайте эти обсуждения: [Голоса против без каких-либо пояснений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277/1365), [Настаивать на оставлении комментария при голосовании против вопроса с репутацией 0](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4013/1365)

Comment: Мои вопросы так вообще позакрывали.

Answer (score 16):

Ну, давайте почитаем справку о том, [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и сравним с тем, что из рекомендаций было сделано в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1461222/179763), который изначально состоял из одной неформатиованной строчки

> Выдаёт ошибку "pip" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом . Что делать?

Итак, что нам говорит справка?

##### Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили тщательный поиск ответа.

Смотрим [поиск по сайту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22pip%22+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9+%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9), видим кучу подобных вопросов. Значит, поиск по сайту сделан не был.

##### Кратко опишите вашу конкретную проблему в заголовке

Заголовок в вопросе `Не работает pip` - говорит он что то о проблеме? Мне - нет, pip может не работать по многим причинам.

##### Сначала опишите проблему, потом добавьте код

Здесь я не спорю, проблема указана, кода нет (я так понимаю тут кода и не надо)

##### Расскажите, как воспроизвести проблему

Этой информации просто нет в тексте нигде

##### Отметьте вопрос всеми подходящими метками

Метка pip была добавлена

##### Сначала перечитайте, потом публикуйте

Справка рекомендует воспроизвести проблему по описанным шагам в вопросе. Но шагов нет, потому и воспроизвести не получится

##### Опубликуйте вопрос и отвечайте на комментарии

Опубликовали, и в комментариях автор не появился.

---

Итого, из 7 пунктов, 2 - выполнено, 5 - проигнорировано.

Я не специалист в питоне и не минусил вопрос, но 5 проигнорированных рекомендаций из 7 может подсказать причины пары минусов на вопросе.

Comment: Могут быть ситуации, что человек не ставит цель задать  хороший вопрос, а просто получить помощь. Новички вовсе и могут не догадываться прочесть рекомендации. Потому скорее нужно подсказать как править вопрос или править самому, а не содействовать закрытию вопроса или разбивать интерес к вопросу.  Думаю к ответам нужно относиться  критичней, чем к вопросам,  Есть конкретный вопрос, пускай будет, если это вопрос, а не просьба или команда выполнить задание за него или  не откровенный бред(согласен с avp
).

Comment: Здесь выше спрашивали почему минусят подобные вопросы, я постарался ответить почему. Хорошо это или плохо - это тема отдельного разговора. Лично я не вижу смысла минусить дубликаты, но я вообще редко кому минусы ставлю.

Answer (score 3):

Иной раз простые вопросы настолько просты, что их достаточно вбить в гугл в том же виде, что их написали здесь, и получить ответ по первой же ссылке максимально подробно. [Этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1461222/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-pip) тому пример, достаточно вбить ошибку в гугл и первая же [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624272/pip-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5), причем сюда же, на RuSO. Прелесть здешнего дизлайка в том, что он показывает, что задающий вопрос не намерен самостоятельно разбираться с темой, проблемой и т.д., а просто хочет готовый ответ. Возможно, что этот вопрос часть какой-то работы в школе/универе, и человек не захотел париться с этим.

Иногда это просто дубликаты, которые разбирались миллион раз здесь, а человек не удосужился проверить вопросы, на которые даны ответы, прежде чем выкладывать свой.

В общем, в половине случаев дизлайки под такими вопросами справедливы.

Что касается вашего второго примера, для меня тоже загадка, зачем его минусовали.

Comment: Если простого вопроса нет здесь или есть, но на него не дан ответ, то ему точно место на _ruSO_. Не надо отправлять пользователей в гугл, не надо ставить минусы, если вопрос гуглится на других ресурсах. Даже если гугл приводит сюда, тогда проголосуйте за закрытие как дубликат и укажите на отвеченный вопрос. Стадный истинкт работает здесь. Один не разобравшийся ставит минус и следом есть пользователи, которые просто не читают и минусят следом. Нам нужны активные пользователи? так давайте не говорить где гугл, а наполнять ресурс актуальными вопросами/ответами вне поля сложности

Comment: По вашей первой ссылке - это дубликат. Если вы откроете вопрос, который указан как решение, вы увидите 122к просмотров. Нужный вопрос? безусловно. А он является "простым"? для меня и для вас возможно да. Но это не значит, что надо посылать человека, который дублирует, ума набираться. Покажите и расскажите, как и что здесь. be-nice

Comment: Этот ресурс не расчитан на вопросы которые гуглятся за 5 минут. Для разжевывания есть Ютьюб где 100500 обучащих материалов на 90% тем.

Comment: @ДенисБеспалов, не могу согласиться ни с одним из вышеперечисленных Вами тезисов. На что рассчитан данный ресурс изложено в  [on-topic](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Имеют место бытьи вопросы которые гуглятся за 5 минут и вопросы, которые гуглятся за минуту, как и вопросы, которые гуглятся за 15 секунд - если все они соответствуют правилам. Относительно разжевивания... Подробный ответ поощряются сообществом и наоборот, поверхностные ответы в которых только изложена только идея или предположение попадают в очередь сообщений низкого качества.

Comment: @ДенисБеспалов относительно YouTube же ситуация далеко не такая как вы описали. Там есть по 100500 одинаковых поверхностных видео на вводные темы, при этом ответов на конкретные вопросы и конкретные проблемы там днем с огнем не сыщешь. Про 90% Вы очень сильно загнули.

Comment: @ДенисБеспалов критерием является не то за сколько вопрос находится в Google, а имеется ли подобный вопрос на StackOverflow. Если его нет - то абсолютно все равно за сколько его можно найти в Google