# Давайте введём функцию, чтобы минус нужно было аргументировать

Tags: обсуждение

Уже не раз замечал, что задав вопрос на ru.stackoverflow - ты вряд ли получишь ответ, но, если ты это сделаешь на англоязычном, то тебе дадут пару правок в вопрос, несколько вариантов ответов, напишут комментарии и покидают ссылок, если твой вопрос не является уникальным. Вот только интересно почему так происходит. Думаете, что дело в количестве и большом посещении англоязычной версии? Может, но никто не задумывался, что дело в нас самих. Почему у них стараются разобраться в вопросе, а у нас сначала минусов накидают даже не обосновывая и просто пролистают.

Вот один из примеров(вопросы были/есть заминусованы):

1. [Горит красным файл в IDEA](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1038052/%d0%93%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-pom-xml/1038073#1038073)
2. [Как поменять уникальный идентификатор в Spring-boot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040311/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-id)
3. [Как проверять значения в базе данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040366/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

И то, какой ответ получил по 3 вопросу на англоязычной версии сайта:

3. [3 вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58627946/how-to-check-values-in-a-database-java/58630885#58630885)

Они сразу покидали варианты других вопросов и разжевали, чем наше комьюните хуже? Почему не сделают, чтобы минусить без аргументации нельзя было. Сделайте возможность тогда, чтобы было клише какое-нибудь для выбора из-за чего минусишь. Пусть модераторы чистят сайт от токсичных пользователей, которые без аргументов стараются унести вопрос пользователя в минусы.

Мне кажется, что сейчас этот вопрос заминусят, но нельзя не высказаться, я покидал варианты только из своих вопросов. Моё высказывание предполагает нести дополнительную ответственность тем, кто слишком часто ставит минусы, если это не является объективным. Пожалуйста, только не нужно говорить про субъективное мнение, вам выдали возможность минусить только потому, что считают вас достойными и набрали нужное кол-во баллов.

Comment: Заминусованы - это громко сказано. По одному минусу на каждый вопрос - это так, досадное недоразумение. Если каждый ваш вопрос кому-то не понравился - не стоит из-за этого особо расстраиваться (вот если бы было -3 или -5 на вопрос, то тогда был бы повод беспокоиться). По поводу ваших предложений уже много раз обсуждалось, см. например: [Голоса против без каких-либо пояснений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277/Голоса-против-без-каких-либо-пояснений).

Comment: По поводу `"Они сразу покидали варианты других вопросов и разжевали, чем наше комьюните хуже?"` - например наше комьюнити объективно меньше: у нас меньше посетителей в сутки, соответственно меньше вопросов и ответов в сутки. Чисто из-за более высокой посещаемости на en.SO вам скорее всего быстрее ответят. Оцените: [10 миллионов посещений в сутки на en.SO против наших 83 тысяч](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic)

Comment: То же самое с количеством участников: 11 миллионов против 173 тысяч. Активных участников еще меньше. Участников, которые могут ответить на ваш вопрос еще меньше. Соответственно, вероятность быстро получить хотя бы какой то ответ намного ниже.

Comment: @insolor Возможно, что громко сказано, но после того, как я выложил этот - статистика немного изменилась и покидали по плюсу. Моё предложение мне не кажется глупым, по поводу аргументации, если минусуешь, потому что новичок(да и не только), который приходит на сайт ещё не всё знает и ему бывает непонятно почему улетает пост в минус. Ведь даже реализовали где-то, но почему не ввели окончательно - непонятно. Минусы влияют на настроение(просьба не говорить, что меня сильно волнует чужое мнение, просто я всегда готов прислушаться, если человек умнее) и то, как люди будут смотреть на твой вопрос.

Comment: `Ведь даже реализовали где-то, но почему не ввели окончательно - непонятно.` -  -2 репутации при минусе на ответ (не на вопрос), плюс предложение оставить комментарий. Введено окончательно. Ничего другого нет и не планируется. `Минусы влияют на настроение` - просьба не говорить, что у вас настроение технически напрямую привязано к минусам на stackoverflow. Вот именно: вас слишком волнует чужое мнение. Вы человек, а не автомат - вы можете выбирать как на что реагировать.

Comment: **У меня противоположная :)**. На ру стаковерфлов меня хотя бы направляли куда искать, _а в английском стаковерфлов меня просто "закрыли", и теперь я там не могу "издавать" вопросы :3_

Comment: Сравните тексты вопросов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1040366/1 https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58627946/1 А итог - вопрос закрыли как дубликат. Если бы не минусы (*Вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться; он непонятен или не несёт пользы*), то, вероятнее всего, не было бы у вопроса 7 редакций https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1040311/revisions. Будьте благодарны, что минус на вопросе побудил вас пересмотреть формулировки самого вопроса. Обратная связь не может быть отрицательной - анализируйте и учитывайте промахи при написании новых вопросов.

Comment: Как это не может, что тут отрицательная связь в себе несёт? [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040311/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b2-spring-boot) [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040366/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Comment: Поставил минус вопросу за несоответствие названия и тела, а также за слабое (никакое) статистическое подтверждение тезису.

Comment: Хорошо, поправил название :) Про тезисы согласен, но раз этот вопрос [поднимали](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) до меня, то он имеет место быть.

Comment: Спасибо что уточнили вопрос. Минус снял. Но все равно не вижу четкого вопроса в теле и сколько-нибудь репрезентативной выборки вопросов/ответов. При том что SO и ruSO на одинаковом движке, дело точно не поправить требованием обоснования минуса

Comment: @Blacit На Ru.SO не по каждой метке достаточно как юзеров, фармящих репу без оглядки на качество ответа (условные "индусы"), так и юзеров, сочиняющих статьи в ответ на вопрос любого качества (условные "просвятители"), поэтому, если вам не повезёт с темой, можно нарваться на категорию юзеров с завышенными требованиями к вопросам и/или недостаточными знаниями. Как повезёт.

Comment: Дело не только в большем количестве людей на en.so. Дело ещё и в том, что там много людей, для которых английский - неродной: индусы, китайцы и мы - русскоязычные. Они банально не могут вступить в обсуждение вопроса, а репутацию-то заработать хочется. Вот и постят готовые ответы из одного кода. Или из чувства альтруизма и желания помочь кидают ссылки. По себе сужу, так же делаю на en.so.

Comment: Если почистить сайт от токсичных пользователей, тот тут останется три с половиной анонимуса... Припоминаю один популярный в прошлом форум: с него ушёл _один_ самый топовый участник и форум резко начал хиреть, т. к. за ним потянулись другие.

Comment: Вроде бы когда-то была статистика озвучена и там были противоположные данные - на ру-SO получить ответ больше вероятности чем на англоязычном.